# How to run a project without npm

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am using Vue.js

I want to use a tree data structure https://github.com/vinz3872/vuejs-tree

This works great if you use npm. But I don't want to use npm. I want to use import from CDN. But I can't get it to work when I import from a CDN. I don’t know how to do this.

I have tried in different ways. I took files from the vuejs-tree/dist package and put them into the project and it still doesn't work.

It seems to me that I am doing something wrong. Can you please tell me how to make it work by importing into an HTML page from a CDN? Not npm install.

**Below I show an example of building a project using npm. I need to translate this into a project without npm.**

**main.js**

```
    import { createApp } from 'vue'
    import App from './App.vue'

    createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Tree
      id="my-tree-id"
      ref="my-tree"
      :custom-options="myCustomOptions"
      :custom-styles="myCustomStyles"
      :nodes="treeDisplayData"
    ></Tree>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Tree from "vuejs-tree";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    'Tree': Tree
  },
  data () {
    return {
      
      treeDisplayData: [
        {
          id: 1,
          text: "Electronics",
          state: { checked: true, selected: true, expanded: true },
          checkable: false,
          depth: 3,
          nodes: [],
        }
      ],



    };
  },



  computed: {


    myCustomStyles() {
      return {

      };
    },


    myCustomOptions() {
      return {
      };
    },



  },


  mounted() {
    this.$refs["my-tree"].expandNode(1);
  },

  methods: {
    
    myCheckedFunction: function (nodeId, state) {
    },

    mySelectedFunction: function (nodeId, state) {
    },


    deleteNodeFunction: function (node) {
    },

    addNodeFunction: function (node) {

    },

  },


};
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Tree structure</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

**1. Import it as a CDN package on the page**

2. Download the JavaScript files and host them yourself
3. Install it using npm
4. Use the official CLI to scaffold a project, which provides batteries-included build setups for a modern frontend workflow (e.g., hot-reload, lint-on-save, and much more)

**I want to use option number 1**

I imported all required packages and it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried "npm run build" and copy the files from dist folder to ur webserver?

Comment: @Tan yes. If I use npm it works great. I don't want to use npm. I want to use import

Comment: The question is unclear on what you want to achieve, and why. Do you want to skip building process with NPM? "It seems to me that I am doing something wrong" - what exactly are you doing? You have `import Tree from "vuejs-tree"`. It's expected to be in node_modules.

Comment: @Estus Flask I don't want to use npm. I want to import to html page <script src="vuejs-tree.js"></script>

Comment: @Estus Flask Without using vue API

Comment: The term is wrong. It's loading. Importing means the use of `import` statement. You can do this for this specific package, because it provides umd module https://unpkg.com/browse/vuejs-tree@3.0.1/dist/vuejs-tree.umd.js . It expects Vue to be loaded, too. If you want to do this on constant basis, you'll cause yourself troubles because a lot of third-party Vue libs don't have prebuilt bundles.

Comment: @Estus Flask Did I understand you correctly that if I import the package (<script src="vuejs-tree.js"></script>), it can cause problems?

Comment: This one likely won't, but the next library will. You need also to load Vue this way instead of importing it in the app, or configure webpack to alias `vue` package to window.vue global. You didn't explain your motivation for this, what you're trying to do is not conventional, there are possible problems but no benefits. You already have to use Node and NPM to set up and build the project because Vue expects it in its usual workflow. I see no reason to not use NPM for a specific package.

Comment: Apparently you did not understand. I'll try to explain.

Comment: @Estus Flask I edited the question. Please see above.

Comment: So this is the first thing that I mentioned, to skip build process with NPM. As I said, Vue has poor support for this. You can't use .vue files without Node and NPM because they aren't valid JS. Without .vue you'll encounter limitations, both features and syntax. You can use vue AND vue-tree with just vanilla JS in theory, but in practice the next Vue lib you'll want to use will require to use NPM any way.